# Web Application Project @Reference tag

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, vs-web-application-project

I am converting a web site project to a web application project in VS 2008 and i've run across a query regarding dynamically loading user controls.

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx" %>
```

and then in the page I simply called...

```
Dim ucSupplierDetails As New ASP.usercontrols_myusercontrol_ascx
```

Sadly when updateing to a web applciation project, this is no longer a valid line. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dynamically load your user controls here is an alternative :

```
Dim ucSupplierDetails As New UserControl 
ucSupplierDetails.LoadControl("~/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx")
placeholder.Controls.Add(ucSupplierDetails)
```

**EDIT :** Here is a second option, put your user controls into a namespace manually :

```
Namespace MyUserControlNamespace

    Public Class MyUserControl Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Don't forget to change your user control's class declaration (Inherits attribute at last line) :

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="MyUserControl.ascx.vb" 
    Inherits="MyUserControlNamespace.MyUserControl" %>
```

And now, you can access them by it's namespace :

```
Dim ucSupplierDetails As New MyUserControlNamespace.MyUserControl
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<%@ Import namespace="Namespace.Of.Your.Usercontrol" %>` instead